# Google Storage Node JS library from Wordpress produces 85 errors

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, webpack, google-cloud-storage, wordpress-gutenberg

I created a Wordpress environment where Node JS libraries are loaded into a Wordpress plugin.

`npm -g i @wordpress/scripts`

`npx @wordpress/create-starter-block x`

`wp-env start`

`npm run start`

I followed the starter guide here https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest

I installed the Google Cloud Storage library with `npm install @google-cloud/storage` but when I import the library with the below code, I get webpack errors.

`const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');`

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js 5:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/x/x/x/node_modules/tunnel-agent'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
 @ ./node_modules/request/lib/tunnel.js 4:13-36
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js 29:13-43
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js 143:18-38
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/src/bucket.js 29:16-34
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/src/index.js 24:15-37
 @ ./node_modules/webpack-google-cloud-storage-plugin/dist/webpack-google-cloud-storage-plugin.js 3:48-80 2806:18-50
 @ ./src/edit.js 34:0-82
 @ ./src/index.js 20:0-26 33:8-12
```

There are 85 variations of the above error, with different package names.

I tried adding the config.js overwrite file with the fallbacks, but this is difficult to do when downstream libraries are also outputting this error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but it's just the addition of the require library that triggers these errors. There is no other JS code.